# How to show detail error from prerender generate on nuxt 3

Tags: laravel, nuxtjs3

I want to generate the nuxt project, using nuxt generate command, but in the end show like this

The Problem :

```
  ├─ /admin/menu/create (1669ms)                                                                        nitro 14:10:49
  │ └── Error: [500]
  ├─ /admin (1709ms)                                                                                    nitro 14:10:49
  │ └── Error: [500]
  ├─ /admin/menu (1717ms)                                                                               nitro 14:10:49
  │ └── Error: [500]
  ├─ /admin/order/today (1755ms)                                                                        nitro 14:10:49
  │ └── Error: [500]
  ├─ /admin/order/history (1980ms)                                                                      nitro 14:10:50
  │ └── Error: [500]
  ├─ /menu (13189ms)                                                                                    nitro 14:11:01
  ├─ /menu/_payload.json (0ms)                                                                          nitro 14:11:01
                                                                                                        nitro 14:11:01
Errors prerendering:
  ├─ /admin/menu/create (1669ms)                                                                        nitro 14:11:01
  │ └── Error: [500]
  ├─ /admin (1709ms)                                                                                    nitro 14:11:01
  │ └── Error: [500]
  ├─ /admin/menu (1717ms)                                                                               nitro 14:11:01
  │ └── Error: [500]
  ├─ /admin/order/today (1755ms)                                                                        nitro 14:11:01
  │ └── Error: [500]
  ├─ /admin/order/history (1980ms)                                                                      nitro 14:11:01
  │ └── Error: [500]
                                                                                                        nitro 14:11:01

 ERROR  Exiting due to prerender errors.                                                                      14:11:01

  at prerender (/D:/Project/Web/rara%20order%20food/fe/node_modules/nitropack/dist/shared/nitro.3d0a4b01.mjs:214:11)
  at async /D:/Project/Web/rara%20order%20food/fe/node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:2986:7
  at async build (/D:/Project/Web/rara%20order%20food/fe/node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:4375:5)
  at async Object.run (/D:/Project/Web/rara%20order%20food/fe/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/build.mjs:92:5)
  at async Object.run (/D:/Project/Web/rara%20order%20food/fe/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/generate.mjs:61:5)
  at async runCommand$1 (/D:/Project/Web/rara%20order%20food/fe/node_modules/nuxi/dist/shared/nuxi.c6444792.mjs:1647:7)
  at async runCommand$1 (/D:/Project/Web/rara%20order%20food/fe/node_modules/nuxi/dist/shared/nuxi.c6444792.mjs:1638:11)  at async runMain$1 (/D:/Project/Web/rara%20order%20food/fe/node_modules/nuxi/dist/shared/nuxi.c6444792.mjs:1770:7)



 ERROR  Exiting due to prerender errors.
```

My nuxt.config.ts

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: [
    '@pinia/nuxt',
  ],
  app: {
    head: {
      title: 'Rafa Order Shop',
      charset: 'utf-8',
      viewport: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1',
      meta: [
        { name: 'description', content: 'My amazing site.' }
      ],
      link: [
        {
          href: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
          rel: 'stylesheet'
        },
        {
          href: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css',
          rel: 'stylesheet'
        }
      ],
      script: [
        {
          src: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'
        }
      ]
    },
    buildAssetsDir: 'assets'
  }
})
```

I want to show the detail of errors, how to do that ?
I want to fix the error while generating on nuxt 3, i dont know how to fix it if has not detail of errors
Thanks Before

Comment: I got these prerender errors because my data was not being fetched properly on the page. Try to render a page with the most simple useFetch: const endpoint = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
const {data: articleData} = await useFetch(endpoint)
const articles = ref(articleData.value.slice(0,5))

Comment: This link helped me: https://github.com/Smef/nuxt-ssg-issue-demo